# C# delete group from keepass database

Tags: c#, plugins

I am building a C# plugin for [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) which creates a password group once authenticated over the web. My problem is I cannot seem to get the group to remove itself once I close the application (in the plugins Terminate() method. Has anyone run into this problem of removing Entries or Groups for KeePass? I can add them perfectly fine (and receive no error on my current Terminate() method. Here's what I have so far. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

```
public override void Terminate()
{
    // Remove event handlers for opening a database
    m_host.MainWindow.FileOpened -= OnFileOpened;

    PwGroup RootGroup = m_host.Database.RootGroup.FindCreateGroup("Test", false);

    foreach(PwGroup group in RootGroup.Groups)
    {
        RootGroup.Groups.Remove(group);

        group.DeleteAllObjects(m_host.Database);

        PwDeletedObject pdo = new PwDeletedObject(group.Uuid, DateTime.Now);
        m_host.Database.DeletedObjects.Add(pdo);
    }

    // Update the main window to reflect changes (only update from the root folder)
    m_host.MainWindow.UpdateUI(false, null, true, m_host.Database.RootGroup, true, null, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a .MergeIn statement which should apply your deletions. At least this works for me on single entries.

```
    private static bool DeleteKeePassEntry(PwDatabase pwDatabase, PwEntry pwEntry)
    {
        try
        {
            PwDeletedObject pwDeletedObject = new PwDeletedObject(pwEntry.Uuid, DateTime.Now);
            pwDatabase.DeletedObjects.Add(pwDeletedObject);
            pwDatabase.MergeIn(pwDatabase, PwMergeMethod.Synchronize);
            pwDatabase.Save(new CoutLogger());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.UpdateLog(e.Message);
            if (e.InnerException != null)
                Log.UpdateLog(e.InnerException.Message);
            return Global.ERROR;
        }
        /* success */
        return Global.OK;
    }
```